# how to use the closest function using specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I need jquery to get the closest id,once the the image is visible. 
this is my query so far

```
(...)
if(isonscreen)
{
    //this works, but I need it to find only images inside the content-bubble div tag
    // and of course this grabs any image no matter what div the image is inside of
    console.log($(this).closest('img').attr('id'));
}
(...)

<div class="content-bubble">
    <h2>{{imageTitle}}</h2>
    <img src="loading.gif" id="lazyload{{imgId}}" class="content-bubble-img"">
</div>
```

I've tried this but its not working and returns undefined

```
console.log($(this).closest('.content-bubble-img').find('img').attr('id'));
console.log($('.content-bubble-img').closest('img').attr('id'));
```

Comment: What is $(this)? What is the context?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/ I think you are making a wrong assumption about what `closest()` does. What meaning of "closest" are you looking to use here?

Answer (score 2):

I thing you want the function `find()`, not `closest()`.

Answer (score 0):

`closest` finds the nearest parent of an element, while `find().filter(':first')` finds the first children inside an element. Or to say it with the doc's words:

closest:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

find:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

http://api.jquery.com/closest/
http://api.jquery.com/find/

To comment your code:

```
console.log($(this).closest('img').attr('id'));
```

This is actually pretty bad since images cant have children, this does only work since `closest()` returns the selected element itself which is the image when you use `$(image).closest()`. Replace `closest` with `find` and you're good to go.

Comment: You would be better off using `.children(':first')` as it will not recursively get all elements beneath it. Only the first level.

Comment: closest does not do this either, so the equivalent would be find since it looks at all the children, closest looks at all the parents.

Answer (score 0):

If u have to find all images inside "content-bubble div" no matter what div the image is inside of then use this :

```
$('.content-bubble img');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be much easier to fully understand what you're trying to achieve if you have added a fiddle of it.

Nevertheless I'm guessing that you're checking whether an image is currently visible - which means that in this piece of code

```
(...)
if(isonscreen)
{
    console.log($(this).closest('img').attr('id'));
}
(...)
```

`$(this)` actually refers to the image you're interested in - thus you might want to simply retrieve its id attribute with `$(this).attr('id')`

Since you want to limit it to images which are placed in divs with a specific class, you might just want to check if one of its parents has class '.content-bubble', by

```
$(this).parents('.content-bubble').length
```

You may also use closest, since it actually traverses up the DOM tree from the element you specified, and:

```
if($(this).closest('.content-bubble').length)
```

which in this case would return true when `$(this)` or any of its parent has class .content-bubble

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the espy plugin for jquery

This is how you find the id of the nearest image inside a div tag 
once the image is visible

```
$('.content-bubble-img').espy(function (entered, state) {
    if (entered)
    {
        // element entered the viewport
        // state === 'inside'
        console.log('element entered viewport');
        console.log($(this).closest('img').attr('id'));
    }
    else
    {
        // element left the viewport
        if (state === 'up')
        {
            // element is now above the trigger area
            console.log('element left the viewport');
        }
        else if (state === 'down')
        {
            // element is now below the trigger area
            console.log('element below the trigger area');
        }
    }
});
```